# Using SignalR hub from another app

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr.client

I have two asp.net applications with windows authentication.
**App A:** has SignalR hub

```
[HubName("docHub")]
public class DocumentHub : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DocumentHub>();

    public void ReloadMenu()
    {
        Clients.All.ReloadMenu();
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        Clients.All.Reload();
    }
}
```

**App B:** calls `App A`'s hub method using `SignalR client`

```
public void CallHub()
{
    var url = string.Format("http://{0}/signalr/", HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled ? "localhost:2051" : "kms.local");
    var hubConn = new HubConnection(url, false);
    hubConn.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var hubProxy = hubConn.CreateHubProxy("docHub");
    hubConn.Start().Wait();
    hubProxy.Invoke("Reload");
    hubProxy.Invoke("ReloadMenu");
}
```

my problem is when it comes to `hubConn.Start().Wait();` line, I get `Unauthorized` exception. stacktrace:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpClientException 
    Exception message: StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
  Date: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 07:16:27 GMT
  Content-Length: 6286
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunTask>b__0(Task`1 t)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://kms.local/WebDav/filename.xlsx 
    Request path: /WebDav/filename.xlsx 
    User host address: 172.00.00.00 
    User: DOMAIN\username 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 61 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunTask>b__0(Task`1 t)
```

since both apps has windows authentication method, I don't know how to authorize app b's request.